# How do I format server side Jquery Datatable rendering date from a timestamp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, datatables, timestamp

I am hoping someone has figured out the issue I am having. I have an ajax call to my MySQL database. I am using ColdFusion and jQuery datatables to display my fields. Everything works fine except when I try to format the date. I have tried to use `<cfset>` to format the date prior to the JavaScript and I have tried a number of other solutions found online. Below is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#TableData').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "MyCFMCall.cfm",
    "aoColumns": [{
        "sName": "ID",
        "sClass": "hidden"
      },
      {
        "sName": "DATABASE_DATE",
        "sTitle": "APP DATE",
        "bSortable": "true"
      } //<!---My timestamp from the database--->

    ],

    "columnDefs": [

      {
        "render": function(data, type, row) {
          return "+row[1]+";
        }, //<!---This will render the timestamp only, yet not formated.--->
        "targets": 1
      }
    ],
  });
});
```

If anyone can show me how to format this rendered timestamp into a more readable format I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What's in your `MyCFMCall.cfm` code?  You can either format the date using the mySQL [**DATE_FORMAT**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function or you can use ColdFusion [**DateFormat**](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/DateFormat.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

you should look into moment.js for parsing the timestamp. maybe this answer would be of some help
[Convert Date from one format to another format in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500694/convert-date-from-one-format-to-another-format-in-javascript)

Also, if you could tell me what format is the date actually in when you recieve it from the server? and do look into the 2nd answer there to avoid using a library.

Comment: Yes, he has multiple options to format the date, but since he can format it server side, it won't require including a new js library if not needed.

Comment: there are also a few functions written in javascript available on that page. if he really wants to do it in jquery he can look into that.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I was able to get it done by adding the following to the query. DATE_FORMAT(YOURDATESTUFF,'%Y-%m-%d %r') AS SortOrderDate