# How to convert "12/20/2018 1:30 AM" format to the YY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-datetimepicker

I have to store the date in the database using this format `YY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`  but I get this  `12/20/2018 1:30 AM` after select date from the kendo-datetime picker.

I have tried `fomat="YY-MM-SS hh:mm:ss"` but its not working every time getting above the same format.

Tell me, anyone, how to convert selected date and time to `YY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`?

```js
var date = object.dTime;
var newdate = date.split("/").reverse().join("-");
```

Comment: What if your users don't have English date format?

Comment: i don't understand sir what are u saying?

Comment: Maybe you've simply misspelled `format=` as `fomat=`?

Comment: can you add minimal code which replicates this here? it'll be easier to help that way

Comment: sir i will check after update not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500694/convert-date-from-one-format-to-another-format-in-javascript

There is already answer for this, Using moment you can convert date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) library in order to format the date into whatever way that you want to display,

```
moment(date).format('YY-MM-SS hh:mm:ss')
```

For more detail, look at [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use in angular moment js please read moment js implementation.
or you can follow this link both question are something same .

[[format date with moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993913/format-date-with-moment-js][1])

Answer (score 0):

In your html file use this

```
<input kendo-date-picker
    k-format="'dd/MM/yyyy'"
    ng-model="model.Date"
    name="Date" required />
```

Comment: since you are using kendo date time picker this is the most relevent solution since it uses inbuilt kendo method for doing so.

Answer (score -1):

```
var date = new Date('12/20/2018 1:30 AM')
date.toISOString().replace('T', ' ').substring(2, 11) + date.toTimeString().substring(0, 8) // "18-12-19 01:30:00"
```

Comment: Add some explanation perhaps.